# Firebase image upload with swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

When i run code, completion handler block does not working.When line work `mediaFolder.child(userId!).putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in` image file upload in storage but code does not running in block. This is my code :

```
if let data = self.profileImage.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
{
    mediaFolder.child(userId!).putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
    if error != nil {
      // errror 
    } 
    else {
      //enter code here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see below code to upload image data to Storage and get the download url

```
var imgData: NSData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((self.img_Photo?.image)!, 0.5)!)
self.uploadProfileImageToFirebase(data: imgData)

func uploadProfileImageToFirebase(data:NSData){
    let randomPic = parentVC?.randomString(length: 10)
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Profile_Pics").child("\(userId ?? randomPic).jpg")
    if data != nil {
        storageRef.putData(data as Data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if(error != nil){
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
                return
            }
            // Fetch the download URL
            storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    // Handle any errors
                    if(error != nil){
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

                    let urlStr:String = (url?.absoluteString) ?? ""
                    print(urlStr)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```